# How does UIWebView implement pagination?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I need to make some customization of my ePub book. And I wonder is it possible to understand how does UIWebView divides itself on pages? I know ho to make this programmatically I wonder how it is implemented inside UIWebView.
Perhaps it adds some tags ("div" or may be smth else) to achieve such effect? 
I know that it is not the open source component but I only nead any suggestions to make my further decisions.

Hear I put an image what I mean.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
arrHtmlPage=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"2",@"3",@"5",@"6",@"8",@"9",@"11",@"13",nil];

NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

NSString *htmlTemplateLink = [bundle pathForResource:@"2" ofType:@"htm"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlTemplateLink]];

wview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 940)];
wview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[wview loadRequest:request];
wview.delegate=self;

wview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

[self.view addSubview:wview];
```

And do this also

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIWebPaginationMode) {
UIWebPaginationModeUnpaginated,
UIWebPaginationModeLeftToRight,
UIWebPaginationModeTopToBottom,
UIWebPaginationModeBottomToTop,
UIWebPaginationModeRightToLeft
}
```